# Symfony2 Ajax getting many requests from one script error

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a very strange problem with my ajax requests. I have a code, that increases the quantity of products by one every time I press a button. The code kinda works but I have a problem. When I press the button I am not getting one request, but 4 at the same time! I have no idea how is that even working, but it happens.

So instead of increasing the products by 1 and finishing it increases by 1 four times!!!

Its a simple script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function (e) {
    $this = $(this);   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'add/quantity',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {product: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').data('id'),quantity: $this.parent('.input-append').find('input').val()},
        success: function (data) {      
          if(data.success == false){
           alert('error')
          }else{
            document.location.reload(true);
           }
        }
    });
});   
});
```

and the controller:

```
public function addQuantityAction( Request $request ) {
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $requestData = $request->request->all();
    $productid     = $requestData['product'];
    $quantity = $requestData['quantity'];
    /** logic*/
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->find($productid);
    $qtyAvailable = $product->getStock();
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $cart = $session->get('cart', array());
    if ( $qtyAvailable > $cart[ $productid ] ) {
        $cart[ $productid ] = $cart[ $productid ] + 1;
        $response->setData(array('success'=>true,'message'=>'Qunatity increased'));
         $session->set('cart', $cart);
    } else {
        $response->setData(array('success'=>false,'message'=>'Out of stock'));
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Why is that even happening??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have multiple listeners to the click event. It's a javascript issue, for sure.

You can tryt this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).off('click', '.add');
    $(document).on('click', '.add', function (e) {
```

Maybe if there is any parent with the same listener, it can happened too. You can use e.stopPropagation(); to avoid it

I hope it helps.

Comment: Appereantly, it was a parent problem.. Thank you for the help!